# Wordpress theme development - the template dropdown in Pages and disappeared

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am developing my own theme.  I have always seen the template dropdown in pages but now the template dropdown is suddenly gone.  Any reason and how to do I get it back?  No errors seen on page.  The other pages that were previously assigned templates, continue to work.

[image: Template dropdown is missing]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possibility is that in your visibility settings, I would check to see if the visibility is off. To achieve this, click the menu (three dots on the top right) >> Panels and see if its off there.